# Discord.js v13 inviter is null

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
const guildInvites = client.invites.get(member.guild.id) 

const invites = await member.guild.invites.fetch()

const invite = invites.find((x) => guildInvites.has(x.code) && guildInvites.get(x.code).uses < x.uses) || guildInvites.find((x) => !invites.has(x.code)) || member.guild.vanityURLCode;
```

What's it going to be like here in v13? inviter keeps saying null, v12 is fine, but v13 has it

Comment: According to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Invite), the `inviter` property is not guaranteed to be available.

Comment: @MrMythical [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Invite) but it is working in v12

Comment: I think there might be an Intent you need to see invites info. Probably the `GUILD_INVITES` intent.

Answer (score 0):

To get the invites you need to enable the intents,
while creating your client you need to put this intent: `GUILD_INVITES`
which will leave it look like `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INVITES`

if it didn't work maybe add `try catch` since the invite property isn't guaranteed but it does exist, you can check more in the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Invite)